# Download a file without direct URL using selenium

Tags: c#, vb.net, selenium, selenium-chromedriver, webautomation

I am using Selenium for website automation in Chrome using vb.net, I want to download the files from a website which don’t have direct URL for download buttons (downloads which triggers from JavaScript) how to do this in selenium in .net (C# or vb.net)?

If it is not possible I want to get notified when user clicked on a download button and control the things like, Set download path and download complete event.

If download path setting is not possible then at least I want to get the downloaded path after completion of download. 
How to achieve my requirements?

Please help me.

Answer (score 3):

Downloading can be a tedious task depending on the browser you are using. Luckily you are using Chrome which shouldn't be too much trouble.

First of all you will need to locate the button that starts the file download.

```
driver.FindElement(<locator here>).click()
```

Now the download should have started. However the download might take a little while before it's finished. Therefore you'll have to poll the downloads folder for new files (or a specific file if you know the file name). You can specify a downloads folder at the creation of your driver.

```
var options = new ChromeOptionsWithPrefs();
        options.prefs = new Dictionary<string, object>
        {
            { "download.default_directory", "path/to/downloads/folder" }
        };
        RemoteWebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver("path/to/driver", options);
```

Now you can find the latest file in this folder by doing

```
var directory = new DirectoryInfo("path/to/downloads/folder");
var myFile = directory.GetFiles()
             .OrderByDescending(f => f.LastWriteTime)
             .First();
```

In a loop you can compare this filename to the filename of the file you just downloaded. Add a timeout to this loop and if it isn't downloaded within the expected time you can fail your test.

Note: I'm not familiar with this language so some of the code may not be fully working, but it'd give you the idea

Comment: Thank you I will try to implement it. Do you know how to accept the download popup programmatically ? chromeOptions.AddUserProfilePreference("disable-popup-blocking", "true"); is not working for me.

Comment: @ITresearcher It depends on the browser. On firefox you can disable it. On Chrome you shouldn't get a breaking dialog, just the bar at the bottom. You can't deal with this using selenium so you'd have to look into using something like AutoIT. I've never used that so I can't help you further with this.